# Suggestion for generation Drupal block views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a Drupal site where I have to show a story on home page which I am calling the cover story.

So I have added a new field in content type called "Cover story" which is boolean value true or false.

Site must have only one cover story.

Then I have added a view create block which show a cover story on home page.

I have also add another block which show latest stories but should not include the cover story so I have add check show only stories which is not cover stories.

But now I want that when admin selects the cover story the old cover story values need to change to 0.
Is this possible using Drupal 7 CCK or do I need to custom code this?

My problem is when there are 2 many cover stories then it not coming in latest stories block. I dont want to manualy search the old story and unchecked the cover story.

Let me know if anyone have suggestion

Comment: Why don't you sort by update date? I think you'll have to search and update your story if the update sort doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the rules module to achieve this. You should be able to switch the boolean value of all the other nodes triggered by the saving of a new Cover Story node.

http://drupal.org/project/rules

Comment: i checked the rules module. i have found it's liltle difficult so i have written 1 small module and with the help of hook_node_insert and hook_node_update i am remove other nodes from cover story.